# How to fix flickering in IFrames?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Iframes in html. for loading multiple html files into single html file .

The problem is when i navigate one page to another i am gettting flickering.

how to fix the flickering in iframes. Also i am using Dhtml Filters and transitions in that.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you are trying to do Ravi? could you provide us with a link to your page where the problem occurs?

Answer (score 3):

The web is, thankfully, not Powerpoint. You can [pretend that it is though](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(VS.85).aspx#Interpage_Transition), but, happily, only for Internet Explorer users.

As some time has passed since I initially wrote this answer, the more disturbed recessed of my brain suggest that you could create a duplicate iframe, position it below (in z-space) the first, and (when the onload event of the frame fires) [animate](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/animation/) the opacity of the original iframe from 1 to 0 before removing the element entirely.

Answer (score 0):

$('#yourcontent').load(url, 'param=value' post || get {param: value}); jquery('#yourcontent').load(url, 'param=value' post || get {param: value});

With this method you don't need iframes, although javascript is required. I'm assuming you already don't mind required javascript.