# Lightbox with IFrame is flickering when clicking on links

Tags: javascript, iframe, popup

I've got the same problem with this post:
[How to fix flickering in IFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877449/how-to-fix-flickering-in-iframes)

Unfortunately, there's no solution (and I'm afraid of negative ratings too :) ).

I can't provide a page where you can see the behaviour (as it's intranet) - but I'll try to explain it:

When I open an external page via lightbox, I get a disturbing 'flickering' when clicking on links... i.e. I try to open an image gallery located on an internal server - clicking on the "next" link lets the page flicker before moving on to the next page.

If I open any other web page (google, some newspaper, ...) I do not get this behaviour - it's much faster, so it seems like the content of the first page is replaced by the content of the next one. In my image gallery it's much slower: the first page disappears, then the next page appears. I get this flickering only with lightbox-popup, not, if I load the page in another window.

I tried differend JavaScript frameworks (jQuery, Scriptaculous, Standalone) - so I guess it's my image gallery which causes this behaviour... any ideas?

It would be really (!) appreciated... thanks!

Best regards,

Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Max mentions, source would be useful.

Also, try using [Fiddler](http://fiddlertool.com) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com)'s Net panel to look at the actual HTTP requests that are being made - perhaps your image gallery is POSTing to itself before redirecting to another page?

Comment: @Max & DDaviedBrackett...

thanks a lot for your answers...

The link is always referring to the same page, but the parameters are variable:

/.../.../200906191117_1.882222.html?[...]&imageNo=3
/.../.../200906191117_1.882222.html?[...]&imageNo=4
...

is it possible that there's a connection?

And, by the way - Safari behaves correctly...

Comment: what is the *sequence* of HTTP requests that happen when you click the link?  Is the current page being reloaded before control is passed to the second page?  Without more details, this will be hard to solve.